# Isotope with Bootstrap 3 and Sticky Footer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky-footer, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope to present a grid of images within a Bootstrap 3 framework.
I've got a sticky footer (using recommended absolute positioning with bottom set to 0).

When the browser window is reduced in height, the div containing the isotope-d images doesn't stop where the sticky footer begins - so the bottom-most 60px of the div (actual amount depends on height set for footer) is hidden by the footer OR extends below the footer. The difference is determined on whether I set a height for the container divs.

Here's the html from https://codepen.io/marklsanders/pen/KrRVaK:

```
the codepen contains an example
```

I'm guessing the problem is caused by the fact that all the images positioned by Isotope are absolutely positioned.
Any suggestions as to how to work with this correctly?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your footer from `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;`, and add `padding-bottom: 75px;` to your `<body>`.

Bear in mind that when you position absolute or fixed, that element is removed from the regular flow of the document. When you position it, it will most likely conflict with another statically positioned element.

In this case, adding padding to the body 'simulates' in the regular document the space that is actually occupied by the footer.

Additional note: The sticky footer approach generally means you'll need to set a fixed height for your footer. I've used 75px for the padding on the body, but you can fiddle with this for best results.

Comment: Many thanks. Perfect. i forget the basics sometimes :)